# .lit file reader on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, document

I want to read .lit books on Ubuntu 14.04 without converting the file. Please suggest me a reader which can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use **calibre** -  supported input formats are:

MOBI, LIT, PRC, EPUB, ODT, HTML, CBR, CBZ, RTF, TXT, PDF and LRS.

To install the latest version of **calibre** - currently  2.40.0 - open a terminal and execute:

(**recommended**)

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

Alternatively run:

(**not recommended**)

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

You can also install from SoftwareCentre

Refer http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

Answer (score 1):

Try calibre

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```